# Unable to associate another role for my ec2 inside notebook via SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

I'm not able to associate a new role for my EC2 instance created via : CreatePresignedNotebookInstanceUrl.

I've created a notebook instance via sagemaker like here : [cloud.hacktricks.xyz](https://cloud.hacktricks.xyz/pentesting-cloud/aws-security/aws-privilege-escalation/aws-sagemaker-privesc). I've got my EC2 instance hosted in an AWS-owned account.  When I do :

```
aws sts get-caller-identity 

{ 
   "UserId": XXXXXXXXXX
   "Account": YYYYYYYYY
   "Arn":"arn:aws:sts::YYYYYYYYY:assumed-role/sagemakerRole/SageMaker
  
}
```

With this role it's not possible to do `aws s3 ls` which is normal so I've tried to associate another role **MyNewRole** which contains : ***AdministratorAccess***, ***AmazonS3FullAccess*** and ***AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore*** :  `aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile --instance-id <ec2-instance-id-of-notebook> --iam-instance-profile Name=MyNewRole`

It gives me :
An error occured (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) when calling the AssociateIamInstanceProfile operation: The instance ID  does not exist.

How is that possible that it could not found the instance? o_O
Is it because it's hosted in AWS-owned account??

Comment: Have you tried following this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-roles.html

Comment: @ya24 Yep i've open the jupyterLab and launched a terminal inside my notebook. But do we launched `sagemaker.Session()` in my terminal notebook

Answer (score 1):

To update an IAM role for a SageMaker notebook instance, you'd have to stop the notebook instance and update the notebook's associated IAM role.
Console instructions - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-update.html

If you're using the CLI, use the [stop-notebook-instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/stop-notebook-instance.html) and [update-notebook-instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/update-notebook-instance.html) calls.

For example,

```
aws sagemaker stop-notebook-instance \
--notebook-instance-name my-notebook-name

# wait until the notebook is stopped and then run the update command
aws sagemaker update-notebook-instance \
--notebook-instance-name my-notebook-name \
--role-arn my-new-role
```

You can also attach these policies directly to your SageMaker assumed role (instead of updating the notebook's role).

While SageMaker notebook instances use EC2, the service is AWS managed, so you won't be able to update the EC2 instance directly (you won't see the EC2 instance in your list of running EC2 instances for the same reason).

Comment: thanks for your reply, after launching this command :  `aws sagemaker update-notebook-instance --notebook-instance-name  my-notebook-name --role-arn my-new-role`  and restarted my notebook,  I've  status 'failed' in the aws console. Maybe it's because in MyNewRole i don't have only AmazonSageMakerFullAccess instead I have AdministratorAccess, AmazonS3FullAccess and AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore?

Comment: Hmm shouldn't be the case, AdminAccess would pretty much allow for all permissions. Can you check the trust policy for the role and ensure it allows `"sagemaker.amazonaws.com"` as a service principal?

Comment: Yes, that's the case my trust policy is correct. Is it because **MyNewRole** doesn't contain `AmazonSagemakerFullAccess` as policy but only `AdministratorAccess`, `AmazonS3FullAccess` and `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore `??

Comment: No, AdministratorAccess has * on *, AmazonSageMakerFullAccess is a subset of the permissions. Can you `describe-notebook-instance` and check the reason for failure?

Comment: It seems working fine now :)